# Unable to write to csv file

Tags: python, append, typeerror

I have created a Harry Potter ordering system. What I am trying to do is, when the user purchases the product using the value entered in(name of product), it checks if the product is in stock, which is saved in variable `D`.

When the user has purchased the product, I want the program to update the value stored in variable D in the `ABC.csv`. (if there are 10 in stock and the customer buys 2 then I want the file to update the value to 8).

Problem 2: I then want the program to check if the value in `D` is `=< E`. If it is, I want it to create another file and write the value in variable `A`and `E`.

```
f = open("ABC.csv","r")
for line in f:
    p = line.split(",")
    A = int(p[0])
    B = p[1]
    C = float(p[2])
    D = int(p[3])
    E = int(p[4])
    F = int(p[5])
    quantity = input("quantity")
    S = D-int(quantity)
    f.write(S(p[3]))
    f.write(",")
    f.close
```

---

I keep on getting this error:

> f.write(S(p[3]))
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Are you sure that D (and p[3]) are populated?

Comment: This seems like a good place for a database. Getting started with `sqlite` is actually pretty easy.

Comment: `S` is an `int`, and the expression `S(...)` tries to treat that `int` as a function.

Comment: How can i prevant it from seeing it as a function?

Comment: yes D(p[3]} is populated.